# jQuery and DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been using

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#EmployeeTable').DataTable({
    paging: true,
    });
});
```

in my external js file in according to this

https://datatables.net/

It works as in table formatting, but the search bar and pagination aren't working

Am I missing something?

https://jsfiddle.net/mustdos/vagnbrLs/1/

Here's the jsfiddle with Employee section being active

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? (Typically, use F12 to open it). See [this basic example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) and note the 2 JavaScript libraries which are also listed.

Comment: Also, double-check the [installation steps](https://datatables.net/manual/installation).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mustdos/vagnbrLs/1/

Comment: Checked them, I already have all of the links. Here's my jsfiddle, note that only the Employee section is active here

Comment: That's a lot of code. My suspicion: It looks like you are loading data into the HTML table in your JavaScript asynchronously. While this is happening, DataTables will initialize - and will think the table is empty. So, you will see your data in the HTML table, but DataTables will behave as if the table is empty. That is why it displays "no matching records found" when you perform a filter.  My suggestions: (1) Put the DataTables initialization code into a callback - and (2) add `angular` as a tag to the question.